# Fixing time-out Error in C

Tags: c, performance, timeout, exit, eof

I am trying to test my program (part of which is below) and I am getting an error that I cannot debug. The input is a string in format "X/Y", and X and Y are assumed to be positive, 1-digit integers. The function "duration" should take in a fraction as described above, and return an integer that is the number of eigths. The denominator passed is always some power of 2 (ie. 0, 1, 2, 4, 8). So, if the denominator is already 8 we can return the numerator as is, and if it is less than 8, we must alter the numerator accordingly, and then return the new numerator. I am getting the following error in my class checker program:

- fraction of "1/8" returns duration 1 -timed out while waiting for program to exit
- fraction of "1/4" returns duration 2 -timed out while waiting for program to exit
- fraction of "3/8" returns duration 3 -timed out while waiting for program to exit
- fraction of "1/2" returns duration 4 -timed out while waiting for program to exit

As you can see, the returns are correct, but I am not exiting properly? When I try to make test files, I cannot send EOF to quit. I think this is one and the same issue causing this.

I tried to make this as specific as possible, Thanks in advance for help

```
int duration(string fraction)

{
    //convert chars to ints
    unsigned int num = fraction[0] - '0';
    unsigned int denom = fraction[3] - '0';

    //check if denominator is 8, if so, return numerator. Else, convert 
    fraction to ?/8
    unsigned int counter = 0;

    if (denom == 8) //no need to convert
    {
        return num;

    else // (denominator is < 8)
    {
        do
        {
            denom = denom * 2;
            counter++;
        }
        while (denom != 8);

        num = num * (pow(2, counter));
        return num;
     }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Last but not least, please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `fraction[3]` -> `fraction[2]` ?

Comment: Oh my goodness, thankyou @PaulR !